# How to change the forms authentication loginurl?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to change the place my website redirects user when they are not logged in.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

It uses the AccountController in the default Controllers folder, the action method LogOn and the View attached to this.

I have another AccountController placed in this folder: Areas/SmallSurvey/Controllers/Account
the name of the action method is the same. I can't figure out the syntax to use.

I have tried different names but none of them work. How do i change it?

Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");        

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                new[] { "MvcApplication3.Controllers" }
            );
        }
```

This is how SmallSurveyAreaRegistration.cs looks like:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "SmallSurvey_default",
                "SmallSurvey/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            context.MapRoute("Login", "SmallSurvey/Account/LogOn",
                new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn" },
                new[] { "MvcApplication3.Areas.SmallSurvey.Controllers" });
        }
```

When trying to access "SmallSurvey/Account/LogOn" i get the following error:

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /SmallSurvey/Account/LogOn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/SmallSurvey/Account/LogOn" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: @Kenci, `it doesn't work` is not a very precise problem description. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: This is the error:

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /SmallSurvey/Account/LogOn

Comment: What happens if you type this url directly in your browser? Are you testing this in IIS or Visual Studio's built-in server?

Comment: Im testing it with the built in server. When typing the url directly in to the browser, it gives the same error.

Comment: @Kenci, so your question has nothing to do with authentication. You have a problem setting up your areas. I see for example that in the `Global.asax` snippet you have shown in your question you have used the `MvcApplication3.Areas.SmallSurvey.Controllers` namespace constraint for the root area which seems wrong to me. You should have used `MvcApplication3.Controllers`. This namespace constraint is something that you should have used for your `SmallSurvey` area route registration.

Comment: I changed it to MvcApplication3.Controllers now. How should i set up the routtable, so my account controller in Areas/SmallSurvey/Controllers/AccountController will work, with the link: /SmallSurvey/Account/LogOn?

Comment: @Kenci, in your `SmallSurvey` area you also have a route registration called `~/Areas/SmallSurvey/SmallSurveyAreaRegistration.cs`. Add a namespace constraint the same way you did in your `Global.asax` but use `MvcApplication3.Areas.SmallSurvey.Controllers` this time. Now you will be able to access the `Areas/SmallSurvey/Controllers/AccountController` using `/SmallSurvey/Account/LogOn`.

Comment: Please look at my edited question. I am still getting the error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I renamed my AccountController in VS, but forgot to rename it in the class. So it was named Account2Controller. It works now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this ~/SmallSurvey/Account/logon
```

[Edit] based on your response.. following should be the route in your area registration..notice the ***area name*** in the route

```
context.MapRoute(

        "SmallSurvey_default",
        "SmallSurvey/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
....
        );
```